# App crashes RGBA in iOS 11 working fine in iOS10 and below

Tags: objective-c, ios10, ios11

While I am opening image picker and selecting Gallery in that the app crashes in iOS 11 but it is working fine in iOS 10 and below

018-02-22 14:42:53.630334+0530[589:98531] *** Assertion failure in -[UICGColor encodeWithCoder:], 
2018-02-22 14:42:53.631850+0530[589:98531] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only RGBA or White color spaces are supported in this situation.'

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"Choose From" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

 // Cancel button tappped.
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        }];
    }]];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Gallery" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        UIImagePickerController *imgpicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imgpicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        imgpicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imgpicker.delegate=(id)self;
        [self presentViewController:imgpicker animated:YES completion:nil];

 }]];
```

Comment: It's difficult to say because you do not provide any code or a stack trace, but I think you are supplying an invalid color space to some API.

Comment: But its working in below iOS 11 I don't know why it happens?

Comment: Apple may have tightened up some internal validation checks in iOS 11.

Comment: I have added everything to info.plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not because of image picker and all.

This is just because of UITabbar I have assigned a background image for Tabbar. I just removed that it works fine now.